# How can I link multiple JavaScript files inside of one linked JavaScript file without using node.js

Tags: javascript

If I have an HTML document with one external JS file attached (I would like to keep it to one) [let's say the file is called index.js] is there a way to link other javascript files from within the index.js file so that the other JS files would also be included?

example structure:

```
/index.html
/index.js
/other-js-file.js
/another-js-file.js
```

So here's what I'd like to do inside of `index.js`:

```
include/import/something-like-that "other-js-file.js"
include/import/something-like-that "another-js-file.js"

function xyz(){
  //do stuff..
}
```

so that my project could access all of the functions in all of the different files.
I am trying to keep the code from the JS files in smaller files for easier maintenance.
I'd also like to do this to avoid having a huge list of JS files in my HTML document.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

An import statement should do just fine

Comment: Could you show an example?